# Build C++ code for Linux environment with Intel C++ compiler in Azure DevOps build pipeline

Tags: c++, linux, azure-devops, intel, icc

I'm seeking advice on how to build C++ code for Linux environment with Intel C++ compiler in Azure DevOps build CI pipeline. It's a common practice if using gcc instead of Intel C++ compiler. But when it comes to Intel c++ compiler, any advice to have a license (either named user or floating) integrated into the build process?

Advice is appreciated!

Comment: Hi yfeng, is there any update for this issue? Does my workaround help?

Comment: Thank you Lance. Your solution is nice and thorough! I'm now getting a linux VM for the workaround solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when it comes to Intel c++ compiler, any advice to have a license
> (either named user or floating) integrated into the build process?

For your scenario, it's recommended to use [Self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) instead of [Hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install).

Here's [the list](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md) of preinstalled software in Microsoft-Ubuntu-hosted agent, we can find that it doesn't contain the Intel C++ compiler. So hosted agent doesn't have the environment to use Intel C++ compiler. Now you need to [install linux self-agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#download-and-configure-the-agent) in one of your local machines which has the Intel C++ compiler environment.

**Note:** *Self-hosted agents give you more control to install dependent software needed for your builds and deployments.*

**Here're some steps for you:**

Step 1: Download and install the `Intel® Parallel Studio XE for Linux` or `Intel® System Studio for Linux`. (Make sure you choose the correct edition and correct version)

Step 2: Download and install the Linux self-hosted agent.

Step 3: Choose your self-agent to run the pipeline. So your pipeline will execute in your local environment which has Intel C++ compiler.

Step 4: Use command-line tasks instead of normal build tasks in your pipeline like [CMD task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), [bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) or [Powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) to invoke the compiler from the command-line. See [Option 1: Use the Command Line](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/get-started-with-cpp-compiler-for-linux/top.html):

- For C source files: icc helloworld.c
- For C++ source files: icpc helloworld.cc

Answer (score 0):

This repo has sample configuration files using intel compilers in Azure DevOps:
https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneapi-ci